# Build failing with an exception in kaptBetaDebugKotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kapt

When I try to build the using command:-
`./gradlew build`

The build failing after some time. This is the exception:-

> PS D:\Git_Kraken\apps-android-commons> ./gradlew build

> Configure project :app
> WARNING: The option setting 'android.jetifier.ignorelist=bcprov-jdk15on' is experimental.
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working wi
> th View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Configure project :wikimedia-data-client
> Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working wi
> th View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :app:kaptBetaDebugKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptBetaDebugKotlin'.

> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
29 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 27 up-to-date

Expecting successful build :)

Comment: Might be worth to include your project and app build.gradle

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.